# Abusive use of "Share" button

Tags: spam, share

Hi :) Our team is making a game for mobile, and now we're developing the shop. 
When you buy something, it displays a "congratulations" pop up. We've added some "share" options on the level Up popup, then... Is it cool to full-fill all the popups with the share button? Maybe the user could detect some awful spamming intentions, but sure is a good thing to let everyone see that there's movement on the game.

Suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: I think it's up for the user to decide if they are spamming or not. I don't see other service preventing "over sharing" since it's beneficial for the service and you are not restricting the user - Stack Exchange doesn't prevent me to share all my replies on my social networks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is the day and age of "sharing". So, having the **share** option for *achievements* and *level ups* in a game makes sense.

### I'd say keep it, but...

Keep a daily limit. Should be simple enough to track that for each user per site (FB, Twitter, GPlus, etc.). I do understand that some users might say, "Hey! Let me decide when it's too much." but shouldn't be that big of a deal.

One way of keeping the user happy is by providing some points (or coins, stars, xp, whatever) for sharing but limit that to *once per day*. When the user taps/clicks on the Share button the next time say,

"You've already earned the sharing reward for the day!"

`Back to Game`     `Share Anyway`

*PS: GTA doesn't allow the player the save the game if too many cheat codes are used so you can try that for the share :P

Although, I wouldn't recommend removing the Share option altogether.*

Comment: ""You've already earned the sharing reward for the day!" That's a really good suggestion. Thank you,

Comment: ""You've already earned the sharing reward for the day!" on the other end you as owner of the product want sharing to be available since day 1 of the user journey since it's a channel to bring new users

Comment: About the GTA example, it's a different concept, you are talking about game mechanics, this issue is about social network engagement.

Comment: @JoaoCarvalho - Yeah, the GTA thing doesn't translate perfectly into this scenario. I just wanted to point it out because the developers are the ones who provide the workarounds as cheat codes and then they are preventing the user from using it. Which isn't a good approach so I thought it would add weight to my suggestion of not removing the Share option

Answer (score -1):

No it's not cool, what is the user trying to do? play a game or spam social media? Also what if they are offline?

Comment: Well it's obviously a really good intention to keep our media contacts away from spam, but we are a business and we have to eat, so we can't forget the socialmedia as a powerfull tool to advertise ourselves. But as is not black and white, I'm asking about where, and how to use it. I will understand that with your answer you are saying that AT LEAST in the shop it's not a good idea :), so thank you.

Comment: No my answer is saying that you need to ask yourself what is the purpose of the game and what is the impact of your interface and app for the user. Is the app/game to make money no matter the cost to the user, or is it to entertain the user and then give them a reason to promote you? The way you describe it it feels like is a spam generation app that does not care about what the user wants and is only there for self promotion.